# Loading Google Maps API V3 asynchronously with dojo.io.script fails silently

Tags: dojo, google-maps-api-3

Smushing Google's [asynchronous loading docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Async) into dojo's [asynchronous loader](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/io/script.html) yields:

```
dojo.io.script.get({
  url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
  jsonp: 'callback',
  content: {
    sensor: 'false'
  },
  load: function() {
    console.log('done');
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('error');
  }
});
```

Or fiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/sKNmS/

The maps JS files are loaded, but the callback is never called.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `dojo.io.script.get()` doesn't support Google Maps' delayed invocation of the JSONP callback.

I've filled a dojo [feature request](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/14063).

Answer (score 0):

`dojo.io.script.get` is only usable for JSONP services.  Your callback is never called because, as far as I can tell, that URL does not return a JSONP-formatted response, just plain JavaScript.

`dojo.io.script.get` sets up a callback, which is expected to be fired by the code returned from that URL.  Since that URL points to plain ol' JavaScript, the function never gets fired, because the response isn't JSONP.

Comment: Does `dojo.io.script.get` require the immediate response to be JSONP?      From [Google's Docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Async), the scripts can be loaded via a JSONP callback, `initialize` in their example.  However, Google's response loads a few more files before it calls the callback.  Sounds like Dojo is cleaning up its global callback prematurely?

Comment: Actually, you're right - looking more closely at the response, the maps code sends the name of the callback function (which looks correct coming from dojo.io.script.get) somewhere to be called later.  However, it's hard to tell how the maps code might be attempting to eventually call it, and it's possible it's doing it in a way that doesn't find the function properly (since dojo.io.script.get generates namespaced callback functions, e.g. `dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript1._jsonpCallback`).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way (tested on dojo 1.6):

```
dojo.io.script.get({
  url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'
}).then(function() {
  console.log('done');
});
```

Since **dojo.io.script.get** returns Deferred object.