# Dojo : load cross domain script dynamically and synchronously

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dojo, synchronization, cross-domain

I'm working on a project where i have to use dojo (i'm doing a custom widget) and the google map api (v3)

For some technical reason, i have to include the google map api through my js file and not through my html file, so i can't use

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places'></script>
```

The load have to be done synchronously.

I've tried some things, first adding the script using

```
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places'></script>");
```

But that's not working, i get a blank page instead, using firebug i can see that the panel "Network" is clearing and the page make an infinite loading of google map api script.

I think i can't do it using dojo.io.script (which allow to make cross domain request), because we can't make synchronous request with dojo.io.script

Any help will be appreciated ;)

Comment: can you take all of the custom widget code to [justpaste.it](http://justpaste.it/) ?

Comment: The widgets code will not help, but someone with a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438854/loading-google-maps-api-v3-asynchronously-with-dojo-io-script-fails-silently) posted something here : http://jsfiddle.net/sKNmS/, that's the same things i'm trying to do with dojo.io.script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, solution was to use google map callback :

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&callback=mapLoaded";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Then make the function "mapLoaded" which execute the code

Thanks for those who taked time to answer me

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to use dojo.io.script. It does not have to be synchronous. The maps API takes a c

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but according to this topic and after some test : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438854/loading-google-maps-api-v3-asynchronously-with-dojo-io-script-fails-silently it's not possible, or i don't find the good way to do it